# Recognized RadGrid command names

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, radgrid

where can i find all of the Command Names for a Rad Grid

**examples**

UpdateEdited
CancelAll
InitInsert
PerformInsert
DeleteSelected
RebindGrid

Comment: Here is the updated link referenced by AcousticBoom:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-command-reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, check the documentation:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-command-reference.html